# Run a function only for a specific Gravity form

Tags: php, wordpress, gravityforms

I have several different forms and I want to run a function that will prefill the fields specific for each form.
I came across a rather simple example:

```
    echo $form['id'];
    
    if ( $form['id'] != 36 ) {
        return $form;
    }

...follow-on code...
```

But the echo returns null and of course the function doesn't run.

My question is, how can I get the form id?

Comment: Are you using a hook or a filter? How do you call the function above? Please read more about https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: How are you rendering your form, via a shortcode, block or the api?

Comment: I'm rendering the form with a block in a WordPress theme.

Comment: I'm rendering the form via a block in a WordPress theme.
I wrote a function that I installed in WordPress and it works when tested outside the site.
I think I'm beginning to see my problem.
The function is running every time the site is accessed, regardless of the page, so Gravity Forms hasn't even been called yet.
What I want is to have this function run when Gravity Forms opens the form.
Then, GF will be able to pass the form ID.
So, it seems I'm looking for a hook to GF. Have I got it right?

Answer (score 0):

When using the block input you can dynamically populate any field with the hook `gform_field_value_` + **field_paramenter_name**.

```
add_filter( 'gform_field_value_field_paramenter_name', 'my_custom_population_function' );
function my_custom_population_function( $value ) {
    return 'hello world!';
}
```

Additional information can be found in the documentation here:
https://docs.gravityforms.com/using-dynamic-population/#block

Personally, I usually render the form programmatically using the [gravity_form](https://docs.gravityforms.com/adding-a-form-to-the-theme-file/#function-call) function which allows you to pass an array of dynamic population parameter keys with the corresponding values to be populate in the form.